# Check for substrings in sequential order using python

Tags: python, string, find, blender, evaluate

I’m currently developing a Blender Add-on that is a lip-sync tool for 2D and 3D animations, and this Add-on includes a Phoneme extractor tool that extracts phonemes from each word.

for example, the sentence `I love pizza` which is `aɪ lʌv ˈpiːtsə`. That’s the reason why I’m making a script that will evaluate each character looking for phonemes in each word (there are like 44 phonemes or something). But to put it simply:

say you have string = `bcda`

I need something like

```
*b detected, do something
*c detected, do something
*d detected, do something
*a detected, do something
```

and in case it is string = abcd

```
*a detected, do something
*b detected, do something
*c detected, do something
*d detected, do something
```

But whatever I do in python I always get `abcd` and I need the sequential order! And it’s even worst because I tried doing this in c# and I did succeed (and I tried using regex, text1 in text2 and .find)

```
text2 = "bca"

aString = "a"
bString = "b"
cString = "c"

if aString in text2:
    print("contains a")
if bString in text2:
    print("contains b")
if cString in text2:
    print("contains c")
```

I tried using .find, using text1 in text2, and even using regex and it works, but not in sequential order

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please do not post screenshots of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). The code snippet also doesn't really show what you're trying to do. If you've succeeded in C#, maybe post that code showing what you're trying to achieve in Python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this just by looping through the string with a forloop and just having a massive switch statment. You could also have a dictionary of phonemes and their acording functions.

```py
aString = "bca"
"""
it got a bit convoluted but the lambda: print("contains a") really just allows you
to call a function (print) with specific attributes, if you wanted your own
function you probably wouldn't need the lambda.
"""
functions = {"a":lambda: print("contains a"),"b":lambda: print("contains b"),"c":lambda: print("contains c")}

for c in aString: # just loops through each letter and calls the according function found in the dictionary.
    functions[c]()
```

which produces:

```
contains b
contains c
contains a
```

If your looking for finding multiple letter occurences here's an approach:

```py
aString = "ac" 
bString = "ba" 
cString = "cb" 
dString = "cba" 
sampleStr = "bcbabac" 
print("**** Iterate over each character using for loop****") 
for elem in range(len(sampleStr)): # Here rather than looping through the characters we loop through the index of each characters
    """
    To break down the if statments:
    The sampleStr[a:b] just takes a substring of sampleStr from a-b (not including b)
    Here the range is from elem to elem+len(aString) (so a substring the size of the phonemes) 
    And then the final min() just avoids situations where the phonemes would be too long and wrap back around.
    So in all we're looping through the String and taking substrings of the size of the phonemes we're comparing it to.
    """
    if aString == sampleStr[elem:min(elem+len(aString),len(sampleStr))]:
        print("detected " + sampleStr[elem:elem+len(aString)])
    if bString == sampleStr[elem:min(elem+len(bString),len(sampleStr))]: 
        print("detected " + sampleStr[elem:elem+len(bString)])
    if cString == sampleStr[elem:min(elem+len(cString),len(sampleStr))]:
        print("detected " + sampleStr[elem:elem+len(cString)]) 
    if dString == sampleStr[elem:min(elem+len(dString),len(sampleStr))]:
        print("detected " + sampleStr[elem:elem+len(dString)])
```

which produces:

```
**** Iterate over each character using for loop****
detected cb
detected cba
detected ba
detected ba
detected ac
```

Comment: This works just fine! But the problem is that I don't want to loop through each character within a string but a set of characters or say for example a substring like "ab" or "cd" and actually I tried your solution and I tried one I came up with and they work! But I can't make them work with a set of characters or "substring" check it out:

Comment: aString = "a"
bString = "b"
cString = "c"



sampleStr = "cba"
print("**** Iterate over each character using for loop****")
for elem in sampleStr:
    
    if aString in elem:
        print("a detected " + elem)
    if bString in elem:
        print("b detected " + elem)
    if cString in elem:
        print("c detected " + elem)

Comment: Also I'm new to both python and stack overflow  (also I'm not a native english speaker) so please don't mind my ignorance and this goes for everyone

Comment: I have added a more general answer that should handle multiple words, also did my best to explain how it works with comments.